# How to enable Promiscuous Mode permanently on a NIC managed by NetworkManager?

Tags: networking, 20.04, network-manager, network-bridge

I'm trying to bridge two of several NICs to act like a switching hub.
To do so, need to enable the promiscuous mode on the NICs.
Even if I set it to “promisc on” with the “ip link” command, the setting will be reset when I reboot the PC.

How can I enable Promiscuous Mode permanently, even if I reboot my PC?

The environment is Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 LTS.
For this reason, the network configuration is based on NetworkManager.

A sample of the minimum configuration is shown below:

```ruby
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.define :bridge do |machine|
    machine.vm.box = "bento/ubuntu-20.04"
    machine.vm.network :private_network, auto_config: false, virtualbox__intnet: "intnet_a"
    machine.vm.network :private_network, auto_config: false, virtualbox__intnet: "intnet_b"

    machine.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
      apt-get update
      apt-get install -y network-manager
      cat > /etc/netplan/50-bridge.yaml <<'EOS'
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    eth1:
      addresses:
        - 0.0.0.0/32
    eth2:
      addresses:
        - 0.0.0.0/32
  bridges:
    br0:
      interfaces:
        - eth1
        - eth2
EOS
      echo 'network: { version: 2, renderer: NetworkManager }' > /etc/netplan/99-NetworkManager.yaml
      netplan apply
    SHELL
  end
end
```

The "ip link" command activates the PROMISC status of the NIC, as shown below.

```text
$ sudo ip link set dev eth1 promisc on
$ sudo ip link set dev eth2 promisc on
$ ip addr
[...]
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,PROMISC,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master br0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether xx:xx:xx:xx:c4:f5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: eth2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,PROMISC,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master br0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether xx:xx:xx:xx:48:57 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether xx:xx:xx:xx:c4:f5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
[...]
```

However, after rebooting the OS, the PROMISC status will be reset.

```text
$ sudo reboot
[...]
$ ip addr
[...]
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master br0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether xx:xx:xx:xx:c4:f5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: eth2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master br0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether xx:xx:xx:xx:48:57 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether xx:xx:xx:xx:c4:f5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
[...]
```

---

In this example, I used Vagrant for the purpose of showing a reproducible environment.
Vagrant is not a requirement, what I really want to use is Ubuntu on a physical PC.
Simply enabling Promiscuous Mode through a Vagrant provisioning run **does not** solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found several methods and solved myself.

### Method 1: Use NetworkManager-dispatcher

```shell
$ sudo bash -c 'cat > /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/50-promisc' <<'EOS'
#!/usr/bin/bash -e
case "$2" in
    up)
        if [[ "$1" = "eth1" ]] || [[ "$1" = "eth2" ]]; then
            ip link set dev $1 promisc on
        fi
        ;;
esac
EOS
$ sudo chmod u=rwx,g=rx,o=rx /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/50-promisc
```

```text
$ sudo reboot
[...]
$ ip addr
[...]
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,PROMISC,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master br0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether xx:xx:xx:xx:c4:f5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: eth2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,PROMISC,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master br0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether xx:xx:xx:xx:48:57 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether xx:xx:xx:xx:c4:f5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
[...]
```

Register a script for `NetworkManager-dispatcher` that will enable promisc when the target NIC (eth1 or eth2) is in the up state.

### Method 2: Register a one-shot service in systemd that is delayed until the network-online.target unit starts

```shell
$ sudo bash -c 'cat > /etc/systemd/system/bridge-promisc.service' <<'EOS'
[Unit]
Description=Makes interfaces run in promiscuous mode at boot
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/ip link set dev eth1 promisc on
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/ip link set dev eth2 promisc on
TimeoutStartSec=0
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
EOS
$ sudo systemctl enable bridge-promisc
```

```text
$ sudo reboot
[...]
$ ip addr
[...]
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,PROMISC,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master br0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether xx:xx:xx:xx:c4:f5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: eth2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,PROMISC,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master br0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether xx:xx:xx:xx:48:57 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether xx:xx:xx:xx:c4:f5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
[...]
```

I think this method can be applied to patterns that do not use NetworkManager.